# Dollar sign in dictionary key name

Tags: python, authentication

I'm trying to log into a website using python, the fields for the username and password contain a dollar sign in their name, How can I get over it?

```
import requests
with requests.Session() as c:
url = 'http://www.somewebsite.com/login.aspx'
USERNAME = 'username'
PASSWORD = 'password'
login_data = dict(ctl00$MainContent$txtLogin=USERNAME, ctl00$MainContent$txtPwd=PASSWORD)
```

The field names are ctl00$MainContent$txtLogin and ctl00$MainContent$txtPwd.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is only an issue because you are calling the dict constructor with keyword arguments. If you used the more normal literal syntax, it works fine:

```
login_data = {'ctl00$MainContent$txtLogin': USERNAME, 'ctl00$MainContent$txtPwd': PASSWORD}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the square brackets and proper string keys.

```
login_data = {}  # or dict()
login_data['foo$bar'] = 'baz'
```